# MVC3 CustomError 500 Issue When Entering HTML Tags In TextFields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I implemented a default custom error page into my MVC3 web application and it seems to be working for the most part.  I can enter a bad URL and my browser is redirected to a default error page without any issues. However, I am having a problem when I add an HTML tag into a text field such as `<br>`.  This is causing a 500 error (Internal Server Error) that is not being redirected to my default error page.

In my web.config I have the following tag.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/CustomErrors/DefaultError" mode="On">
</customErrors>
```

I have a controller called CustomErrors with a view called DefaultError.cshtml.

```
public class CustomErrorsController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult DefaultError()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I enter bad URL a breakpoint I enter in the CustomErrorsController's DefaultError action method. But when I enter `<br>` into a text field such as the log in page I am seeing flaky behavior. IE or Mozilla shows a default browser error page. The odd thing is that when I remove the `customerror` property from my web.config I get an ugly page with the exception being dump on it. So my custom error is somehow being referenced but not fully implemented.

Any ideas with dealing with custom errors and entering html tags in text fields?

Comment: You could define a custom action filter that will show your error page, inside it's `on_exception` method.

Comment: I'm assuming on_exception needs to go into my CustomErrorsController.  I'll give that a shot and let you know of my results. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Adriano for pointing me in the right direction. I found this example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324368/asp-net-mvc-override-onexception-in-base-controller-keeps-propogating-to-applica) and ended up implementing the OnException in my base controller since the exception would not occur in my CustomErrorsController.

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "/CustomErrors/DefaultError"
        };

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```