# ExceptionFilter OnException not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am new at using exceptionfilters.

Following the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#httpresponserexception

I've created a class

```
public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
    }
}
```

then i used the attribute on a single method on my controller. i did not add the filter globally yet because i want it to work on a single method for now.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [NotImplExceptionFilter]
    public void Test()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This method is not implemented");
    }
}
```

But the OnExepction is not being called every time i'm throwing an error. please let me know what am i missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you are inheriting from `Controller` class instead `ApiController` as documentation says.

Since you are using `System.Web.Http` namespace in this attribute it works only for Api controllers.

If you want to use other controllers as well you need to add another exception filter attribute but in that case dont use `System.Web.Http` but use `System.Web.Mvc` namespace and the other part will be almost the same code(*only a few small changes*)

Override `OnException` again and make your logic in there but remember these two ways are different in how you actually show the error message to the user. First one use the response to show the message and the other one has to be implemented in a different way. Probably look at this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324368/asp-net-mvc-override-onexception-in-base-controller-keeps-propogating-to-applica)

Comment: can't do. because i have some actions on my controller that are using views and it will have error if i use apicontroller. does the exception handling only works on ApiController?

Comment: In this case it works only fot api controllers because you are currently using `System.Web.Http` namespace.

Comment: hmm, but is there a way that i can use error handling on a Controller not on ApiController?

Comment: @HVT_08 look at the edit. At the end there is a way how to show a error message to the user. You can make your custom way of doing this but the general idea remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Your other problem is that you are missing the System.Web.Mvc.FilterAttribute, once you apply that, it should trigger as expected. (providing you make the change of using IExceptionFilter/ExceptionContext instead of ExceptionFilterAttribute/HttpActionExecutedContext as has already stated.

Example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method]
    public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
    }
}
```